# Boundary value of weakly convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

If $u_m\in \mathring W_2^{1,1}(Q_T)$, and $u_m$ weakly convergence to $u$ in $W_2^{1,1}$,  then whether $u$ is belong to $\mathring W_2^{1,1}$ ?  How to prove it?

ps:  $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$, and $Q_T=\Omega\times (0, T)$,
$$
\mathring C^\infty(Q_T)=\{u\in  C^\infty(Q_T) : u \text{ is zero near } \partial\Omega\times (0, T)\}
$$
and  $\mathring W_2^{1,1}(Q_T) $
is closure of  $\mathring C^\infty(Q_T)$  in $W_2^{1,1}(Q_T) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know your definitions, but typically the space with an "o" on top is a closed subspace of the other space. Closed subspaces are also weakly closed (by an application of Hahn-Banach).

Comment: I have add the definitions.  Seemly, it is same with what you say.  Could you tell me what weakly closed  means?

Comment: Weakly closed means closed w.r.t. the weak topology. In particular, weak limit points of weakly convergent sequences will belong to the set.

Comment: I am sorry, i still don't know whether $u$ is belong to it.

Comment: I understand, thanks.